# Sum symbol disappearing

Tags: eulervm

Compiling this file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k$
\end{document}
```

the symbol for Sum doesn't appear.

What's going on and how can I make it appear?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Load `eulervm` before `newpxmath`

Comment: Off-topic: What are you trying to achieve by loading two separate math font packages?

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to use the `eulervm` math font package, you shouldn't load any other math font packages -- except if you know exactly what you're doing. (Attempting to load `newpxmath` either before or after `eulervm` does *not* qualify. As you've discovered, loading `newpxmath` before `eulervm` has some bad side effects; and loading it after `eulervm` simply clobbers the Euler math fonts -- all you'll get is the Palatino clone.)

If you do decide to employ the `eulervm` package, you owe it to yourself to load it with the options `euler-digits` and `euler-hat-accent`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[euler-digits,euler-hat-accent]{eulervm}
\begin{document}
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \quad \hat{\alpha},\hat{\beta},\dots,\hat{\omega} \quad 0123456789$
\end{document}
```